# Component not rerendering when passing store manually to components (react-redux)

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am building an application that dynamically renders react components from json definitions. Some of the components need to be rendered with a data context. These components then need to fetch external data. I had a naive solution before to wrap these components with a DataComponent that fires a request during mount then sets the state. This approach works.

```
componentWillMount = () =>
  provider
    .get()
    .then(data => this.setState({data}))
```

Now, I tried to come up with a solution using redux, such that all data schema will have a reducer, and each component does not need to manage its own data (which might come from the same source as other components). The store is initialized properly, and I can see that the store state is updated properly whenever an action is dispatched (I'm using redux devtools to validate, no state is mutated). However, the component is not updated with the new data. The `render` function is not reinvoked after the initial call.

Here's a similar code to what I came up with:

```
import React from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

// Component: React.Component
// store: redux-store
// schema: String
export default function connectedComponent(Component, store, schema) {

    class DataComponent extends React.Component {

        static propTypes = {
            // eslint-disable-next-line react/forbid-prop-types
            data: PropTypes.any
        }

        static defaultProps = {
            data: null
        }

        render = () => {
            if (this.props.data) {
                return this.renderComponent(Component, this.props.data)
            }
            return (<span>empty</span>)
        }

    }

    renderComponent = (Component, data) => ...

    // eslint-disable-next-line react/no-multi-comp,react/display-name
    return (props) => {
        const ConnectedData = connect(mapStateToProps(schema))(DataComponent)
        return (
            <ConnectedData {...props}
                           store={store}/>)
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (schema) => (state) => ({
    data: state[schema][schema]
})
```

Here's the code for the store

```
import {createStore} from 'redux'
import {combineReducers} from 'redux'
import reduce from 'lodash/reduce'
import has from 'lodash/has'

export default (schemas) => createStore(
    createReducers(schemas),
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
)

const createReducers = (schemas) => combineReducers(reduce(schemas, accumulateReducers, {}))

const accumulateReducers = (reducers, schema) => ({...reducers, [schema.id]: createReducer(schema)})

const createReducer = (schema) => {
    return (state = getDefault(schema), {type, response}) => {
        switch (type) {
            case `${schema.id}_GET_SUCCESS`:
                return {...state, [schema.id]: response}
            default:
                return state
        }
    }
}

const getDefault = (schema) => ({
    [schema.id]: getDefaultValue(schema)
})

const getDefaultValue = (schema) => {
    if (has(schema, 'defaultValue')) {
        return schema.defaultValue
    }

    switch (schema.type) {
        case 'array':
            return []
        case 'object':
            return {}
        default:
            return null
    }
}
```

Inside the application, there's also another redux store to manage the renderer state.

Edit 1:
Adding github repo to demo the problem
https://github.com/clydeespeno/redux-custom-store

Edit 2:
react-redux version was 5.0.2, found that there was a bug related to subscription against custom provided store, which was already fixed at least on 5.0.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

react-redux version was 5.0.2, found that there was a bug related to subscription against custom provided store, which was already fixed at least on 5.0.6

Updating react-redux to 5.0.6 fixed the issue. The bug is described here https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/pull/589